# Redirect using PHP rather than redirects in Cpanel

Tags: php, redirect

Probably this question has been asked before but I cannot seem to find a satisfying answer.

I have the following URLs for my website:

```
mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=abc
mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=xyz
mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=mno
```

I would like to create redirects so anyone who  will enter this URL

```
mywebsite.com/abc will redirect to mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=abc
mywebsite.com/xyz will redirect to mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=xyz
mywebsite.com/mno will redirect to mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=mno
```

I would either the URL to be entered as mywebsite.com/abc and changed to mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=abc in the browser's address bar or remain mywebsite.com/abc.

I know how to do this using the Redirects tool in the Cpanel - but it will be much more efficient for me to do it using PHP and/or PDO rather than creating each one manually.

Comment: http://www.php.net/header

Comment: You do not need to create each one manually. [This](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) may help.

Comment: The issue he'll have is it's hard to differentiate between these links and any other page link in trying to automate with a rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for a php way to do this, but you could easily do it with a .htaccess rule, you could add one rule and it will work for all your urls:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This will accomplish what you want:

mywebsite.com/mno will redirect to mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=mno
mywebsite.com/abc will redirect to mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=abc
mywebsite.com/xyz will redirect to mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=xyz
mywebsite.com/mno will redirect to mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=mno

Comment: So I just add your code to my .htaccess only? What if I want URL to remain permantely in my browser like mywebsite.com/mno instead of mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=mno

Comment: Correct just put it in you .htaccess file. It will remain in your browser as mywebsite.com/mno. profile.php will interpret the variable the same as profile.php?id=mno

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect from PHP you can do with headers. For example, create index.php in mywebsite.com/abc which contains

```
<?php
header("Location: http://mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=abc");
exit;
?>
```